# How to use read.table for file with delimiter \t

Tags: r, read.table

I want to read a data file using:

```
ds <- read.table(file="/data/ken/tmp/tt", header=F, 
                  sep="\t", quote="\"", dec=".",
                  fill=T, comment.char="", 
                  stringsAsFactors=F, 
                  colClass=rep("character", 6))
```

The file `tt` looks as follow, with `\t` as delimiter

```
20130129074502\thttp://xxx.com.cn/notebook/asus/526600_detail.html\t\t5025\t526600\t255dkmi
```

but it doesn't work:

```
caution:
In read.table(file = fcon, header = F, sep = "\t", quote = "\"",  :
  cols = 1 != length(data) = 6
```

Comment: Does `\t` represents a 2 bytes string "\t" or `tab`?

Comment: Why not use `read.delim` as it's set up for tab delim files?

Comment: For giggles, try `sep = "\\t"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you over complicate things , Try this :

```
read.table(text=tt)
            V1                                                 V2   V3     V4      V5
1 2.013013e+13 http://xxx.com.cn/notebook/asus/526600_detail.html 5025 526600 255dkmi
```

where tt is :

```
tt ='20130129074502\thttp://xxx.com.cn/notebook/asus/526600_detail.html\t\t5025\t526600\t255dkmi'
```

**EDIT**

You can read line by line, and split using strsplit

```
sapply(readLines(file.name, n=-1),
                 function(x) strsplit(gsub('[\t|\t\\]','@',x),'@'))
```

Comment: that not creact, cause it have 6 cols in the raw data(with 5 '\t'), but you only get 5 cols

Comment: where is the limits of this column? can you show me..maybe I need to split column V2...

Comment: there is a empty string between two '\t', which is like "...detail.html\t\t5025" in the raw data. It seems the function read.table ignore sep if '\t' with an empty string around.

Comment: @catchyoulater I think you need to use `readLines` with some regular expression...